# Submit Button not Working in php script - By Pressing Nothing Happens

Tags: php, html

I do not know why the submit button doesn't work. When I click on it, nothing happens.
What is What is Mistake don't know? 
Here is code:

```
<form action=members.php method=post>

<br><br><Center><table><tr><td colspan=2 align=center><h3>Members Login Area</h3></td></tr>
<tr><td>Member's ID</td><td><input type=text name=id></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password</td><td><input type=password name=password></td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>
<a href="forgot.php" onclick="doexit=false;"><font face="Verdana,Arial,Helvetica" size="1" color="#000000"><b>Forgot Your Password?</b></font></a></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan=2 align=center><input type=submit value="Log In"></td></tr>         
</table></form>
```

Comment: For starters you need to clean that syntax up. Put quotes around html attributes if they are not integers. Get rid of <center>, <font>, width attribute, align attribute and use CSS. Consider putting the h3 and the input button outside of the table instead of using colspan, unless it's crucial for layout or design.

Comment: Try using different browser or may be you have nested forms. This particular form is working well. I tested it on my machine.

Comment: font tag and missing end-tag or /> at the end of inputs is a bit creepy. 
Otherwise, the code is working in chrome, IE, opera and FF. What exactly doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

where is quotes ("). u missed quotes everywhere :P

```
<form action="members.php" method="post">
```

// Your code must be something like this.

```
<form action="members.php" method="post">
  <br><br>
  <center>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center">
          <h3>
            Members Login Area
          </h3>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Member's ID
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="id"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Password
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="password" name="password">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="forgot.php" onclick="doexit=false;">
            <font face="Verdana,Arial,Helvetica" size="1" color="#000000">
            <b>
              Forgot Your Password?
            </b>
            </font>
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center">
          <input type="submit" value="Log In">
        </td>
      </tr>         
    </table>
  </center>
</form>
```

Comment: HTML5 doesn't require that anymore. `action=members.php method=post` is perfectly valid.

Comment: html never required qoutes

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type=submit value="Log In">
```

should be

```
<input type='submit' value="Log In">
```

and its like `type="something"` not `type=something`

the structure of input is

`<input type='keyword' >` and keyword could be [from this list](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input) (w3.org)